# Custom Player Heads not working on Bukkit server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-spigot

I am running a Spigot MC server and I want to get custom player heads, as per [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/zxn7u/its_apparently_my_cakeday_so_lets_cash_in_this/?sort=new). This is all over the [web](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1989571-1713w38c-how-to-make-custom-player-heads-in-game-without-mods/), but I *cannot* get it working in my Server!

When I run the command that is needed `/give playername 397:3 1 player:playername` or `/give playername 397 3 1 {SkullOwner:"playername"}` it just returns

```
Too many arguments.
/give [-do] [-d] <target> <item[:data]> [amount]
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be Commandbook.
Try disabling it and try again.

Comment: How do I do this? Would just moving the plugin .jar out of the folder disable it or do I have to run a command in the server prompt?

Comment: You can just rename the plugin into something.disabled and restart the server.

Comment: YAY! It worked! However, can I restart the server with CommandBook enabled and still have the head as it is?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it would work.

Comment: Worked fine. Heads are up and CommandBook is going fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`/give player minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"playername"}`

Comment: Same error. Too many arguments. This is really very perturbing!

Comment: Huh really? It worked perfectly fine for me. What version are you using?

Comment: `CraftBukkit version git-Spigot-1257 (MC 1.7.2) (Implementing API version 1.7.2-R0.3-SNAPSHOT)` Could this be a plugin conflict? I only have 5 small ones: `Plugins (5): WarpPortals, NoSpawnChunks, ClearLag, WorldEdit, CommandBook`

Comment: Command worked, I just had to disable CommandBook. It *was* a plugin conflict :D

Comment: Huh well that's good to know. Glad you got it figure out.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old, but I have the best solution. Without disabling any plugins, just type:

```
/bukkit:give player minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"playername"}
```

The "bukkit:" in front of the command tells the server it is the Minecraft give command, not CommandBook, or any other give command.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks for this! I'll remember it for the future :D